# RDS RemoteApp with Java

Tags: java, internet-explorer, rds

I am attempting to put together a small RDSH farm to deliver a front-end which requires Java. The front end is a simple VB executable which displays a predefined java-driven web front end.

Now, my first attempt was very successful. I configured a single server to act as broker, licensing server and session host. Dropped the executable into place, installed java and published it as a remote app. Viola! everything worked perfectly.

Some basic load testing showed me that we needed a more robust approach as the server was getting hit hard while users were logging in. As few as about 30 sessions maxed out the CPU.

So, i have now put in place a slightly more complex setup. One server as the connection, broker and licensing server, then two session servers - the idea being i can add in more session servers as required.

Now, all three of these servers are set up essentially the same as the first. I have disabled IE enhanced security mode on all three, have the same Java config as the original single-server setup, and have not changed anything else.

What is happening now is that when the users attempt to connect to the RemoteApp, they are getting a dialog stating that 'content within this application coming from the website listed below is blocked by Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration'. The website listed below is the application server that the java front end runs from.

I have confirmed that all servers (the connection server, both session servers, and the application server) all have IE enhanced security mode disabled.

All servers are 2012 Standard.

Can anyone shed any light on why this might be happening?

Comment: When you logged on to confirm that IE ESC is disabled, did you confirm the computer you were logged on to (hostname.exe or SET CO)? RD Connection Broker has a habit of redirecting you to another server if you connect to a specific server.

Comment: All three are VMWare VM's - i am connecting to the consoles... Avoiding anything to do with RD

Comment: The app runs correctly on all three in a normal RD session?

Comment: The app runs correctly from the console of the session servers - its not installed on the connection server